# Can quartz scheduler use fake time?

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I need Quartz to execute tasks with a fake time. 
In one case, quartz should use a configurable offset in seconds from the current time. So I should be able to tell quartz to do something on 1/1/2000 by configuring the right number of offset seconds.

In another case, I want quartz to accelerate the time so that every passing minute should be treated as 2 or 4 minutes. I want to configure the acceleration factor.

Are the above two features possible with quartz?

Thanks